# Use Spek with suspend method

Tags: android, kotlin, spek, mockito-kotlin

I am trying to create a unit test using Spek framework and nhaarman mockito kotlin in my Android Kotlin project. The problem is that when there is nested suspend method I don't know how to mock response.This is how I'm trying

I defined:

```
    val testCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    val testCoroutineScope = TestCoroutineScope(testCoroutineDispatcher)
```

and before any *describe*

```
    beforeGroup {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher) //not sure if this is working properly 
    }
    afterGroup {
        Dispatchers.resetMain() // reset main dispatcher to the original Main dispatcher
        testCoroutineScope.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }
```

and this is my group

```
    describe("Test view model") {
        val contentRepository by memoized(CachingMode.SCOPE) { mock<ContentRepository>() }
        val contentViewModel by memoized(CachingMode.SCOPE) {
            ContentViewModel(contentRepository)
        }
        describe("When something happens") {
            beforeGroup {
                testCoroutineScope.runBlockingTest {
                    whenever(contentRepository.fetchAllContents(0, 10))
                        .thenReturn(Result.success(content))//This is suspend
                    contentViewModel.setContentPage(0)
                }
            }
            it("should fetch all content from repository with page 0") {
                verifyBlocking(contentRepository) {
                    fetchAllClassContents(0, 10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

But Im getting the following error

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
classContentRepository.fetchAllClassContents(
    0,
    10,
    Continuation at viewmodel.ContentViewModelSpek$1$3$1$4$1.invokeSuspend(ContentViewModelSpek.kt:92)
);
-> at repository.ContentRepository.fetchAllClassContents(ContentRepository.kt:23)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
contentRepository.fetchAllContents(
    0,
    10,
    Continuation at viewmodel.ContentViewModel$setContentPage$1.invokeSuspend(ContentViewModel.kt:26)
);
```

It seem like mock, method execution and assertion are running in different scopes

I can't find any guide that helps me create test with coroutine
Thanks in advance